# Perl script invoke unix command system unzip

Tags: perl, unix, system, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file using a Perl script.  In order to unzip the file I chose to try and invoke the UNIX command system unzip.  My problem seems to be that the command is not reading the variables.

```
my $file_path = "/home/data"
my $file_name = "TEST.ZIP"

system ('unzip $file_path/$file_name');
```

When I run the command I see.

unzip:  cannot find /, /.zip or /.ZIP.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
system ("unzip $file_path/$file_name");
```

Use double quotes if you want to use string interpolation.

Answer (score 4):

Better use a relevant (`Archive::Extract`) module.